# What is Cat 6 cable DC isolation?

Tags: cables, isolation, network

What is the DC isolation of Cat 6 cable, between different pairs and between same pair? I could not find this information in the cable manufacturer's specs.

Comment: Standard PoE runs up to 57v as a phantom voltage between the lines in pairs, so thats almost certainly safe. Above that your getting out of the SELV range, and you probably don't want to be running over data cables.

Comment: Likely it depends on which exact cable type you buy. The rating usually reads on the cable.

Comment: is there something about the voltage printed on the cable jacket?

Answer (score 4):

The relevant specifications for Category 6 are set out in ANSI-TIA-EIA 568-C.2.

First and foremost, there is no DC isolation specification for continuous operation. The dielectric strength specifications mandated by the standards are for transiently applied high voltages, e.g. an ESD event or induced voltage from a lighting strike. This is mostly because the cables are not designed to continuously carry high voltages, and the dielectric strength of the insulation required for fault conditions is more than enough to cover normal operating conditions with existing PoE standards.

The dielectric strength specification for Category 6 cabling is different depending on whether you're using *horizontal* or *backbone* cabling. The main difference is that backbone cabling is suitable for being passed between floors in a building, whereas horizontal cabling is the more general use type that you might see on a cable snake or in a patch panel. Backbone cabling is sometimes referred to as "riser" cabling, although this is technically a separate concept from a standards perspective.

For horizontal cabling, the standards says:

> The insulation between each conductor and the core shield shall be capable of withstanding a minimum DC potential of 2.5 kV for 2 seconds or an AC potential of 1.7 kV for 2 seconds in accordance with IEC 60189-1.

For backbone cabling, the standard increases the requirements:

> The insulation between each conductor and the core shield, when present, shall be capable of withstanding a minimum DC potential of 5 kV for 3 seconds in accordance with ASTM D4566.

These requirements are in addition to the older Category 5 specifications from ANSI/TIA/EIA 568-B, which state the following:

> The insulation between each conductor shall be capable of withstanding a minimum DC potential of 5kV for 3 seconds.

There is no differentiation between inter-conductor insulation specifications for horizontal and backbone cabling in Category 5; all cables must meet the 5kV dielectric strength requirement. This makes sense if you think about it, because there's twice as much insulation between two conductors than there is between one conductor and the core shield. They also make no distinction between intra-pair and inter-pair isolation, because from a mechanical perspective they occupy the same space and the impact of arcing is the same regardless.

The outer insulation of the cable *should* be marked with transmission performance and mechanical performance information, along with other details like fire safety ratings, but it is technically optional and the exact markings that are required may depend on local building codes and other product regulations.

In terms of what voltage you can safely run through the cable continuously, 57V is the highest voltage specified by any official PoE standard, and you should be safe to run any voltage from 0V to 57V through a Category 5 or 6 cable. More importantly, you must also ensure that current limits are adhered to - the highest I'm aware of is 960mA per pair on 802.3bt Type 4 - since excessive current is likely to cause the cable to overheat, melt, short, and/or start a fire. You must include safeguards (e.g. fuses, current monitoring) to ensure that the maximum current specification for your cable is not exceeded. You should also consider the impact of ohmic heating within the cable and use that to derate the maximum ambient temperature you can operate at.

It is entirely possible that you *could* run higher than 57V DC through a Category 6 cable without problems, but I would not recommend it. In terms of the dielectric strength of the insulation, it is very unlikely that 70V, 80V, or even 100V would manage to arc through. However, you are operating fully without a safety net, and you may get arcing in the 8P8C connectors or receptacles, or on the board if it isn't designed with appropriate clearance and creepage distances for the elevated operating voltage.